# Record is Not updated ASP.NET Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, ajax

I tried to update the data but it didn't update. Data is loaded into a datatable with edit and delete buttons, when I click edit button data will be passed in to the relevant textboxes for edit. I attached the screenshot below for easy to understand the problem. If I change the data and click the button data is not updated. Add and edit both things I do at one button.

Screenshot:

[image]

Edit button in the datatable code

```
  "sTitle": "Edit",
     "mData": "id",
     "render": function (mData, type, row, meta) {
     return '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" 
       onclick="get_category_details(' + mData + ')  ">Edit</button>';
```

When I click the edit button it goes to the function `get_category_details(id)` along with record id and displayed records on relevant textboxes

```
function get_category_details(id) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'edit_return.asmx/doSome',
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        data: "{id: '" + id + "'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                            isNew = false;                    
                           id = data.d[0].id
                           $('#fname').attr('value', data.d[0].fname);
                           $('#age').attr('value', data.d[0].age);

                        }
                    });
                }
```

After I make changes and click the button, it is goes to `Addproject()` function
this is button. else part for record updated. This how I sent the record to `update.aspx` page I have two fields fname and age in the form with id means

```
id = data.d[0].id
```

This I send it

```
{fname: '" + $('#fname').val() + "',age: '" + $('#age').val() + "'}" + "&id=" + id,
```

look like this way any problem on that

```
<input type="button" id="b1" value="add" class="form-control" onclick="addProject()" />
```

`Addproject()` function

```
   var isNew == true// if isNew == true means the record is new
```

if it is false mean update one existing record

```
    function Addproject()
    {
        if (isNew == true) {
         _url = 'insert.aspx/doSomething';
          _data =  "{fname: '" + $('#fname').val() + "',age: '" + $('#age').val() + "'}";
         _method = 'POST';
        }
         else {
           _url = 'update.aspx/doSomething',
            _data = "{fname: '" + $('#fname').val() + "',age: '" + $('#age').val() + "'}" + "&id=" + id,
           _method = 'POST';
          }

          $.ajax({                  
                    type: _method,
                    url: _url,
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: _data,
                    success: function (data) {
                    //  alert("success");
                      get_all();

                      var msg;

                      if (isNew = true) 
                           {
                              alert("Data Added");
                            }                       
                            else
                            {                    
                               alert("Data Updated");
                            }

                        });
                    }
    }
```

This is code for receiving  the data and update the record at update.aspx

**update.aspx**

```
public class UserClass
        {
            public string fname { get; set; }
            public int age { get; set; }
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string doSomething(string fname, int age, int id)

        {      
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=.; Initial Catalog = jds; Integrated Security= true;");
            string sql = "update record set name ='" + fname + "', age ='" + age + "' where id = '" + id + "')";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            return "Success";
        }
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: if you write the code sir it helpful one for correct the mistakes

Comment: You didn't specify if the data is not being updated in your database or if your gridview doesn't show the updated values (assuming that you're suing a gridview control)

Comment: i am not using grid view sir .datatable i used with ajax.  i attached image above. {fname: '" + $('#fname').val() + "',age: '" + $('#age').val() + "'}" + "&id=" + id,  this how sending data in to update.aspx is there any thing wrong

Comment: again. you're not explaining what doesn't get updated, the data in the sql database or values displayed in the gridview.

Comment: data in to the sql database sir doesn't updated

Comment: did u try setting a break point in your webmethod to see if it gets hit? Did you check browser console for errors?

Comment: update.aspx/doSomething:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)     update.aspx/doSomething:1   this error displayed  after make the changes and click the button . C# no errors shows

Comment: also, since you're using ajax and not good old postback, you can't call databind on your griview to show updated values

Comment: so how can i write it sir.canyou write the code for me it is more helpful for me thanks

Comment: No, I will not write code for you. I suggest you google "asp.net webforms crud"

Comment: ajax how to write it bind the values {fname: '" + $('#fname').val() + "',age: '" + $('#age').val() + "'}" + "&id=" + id,  is it correct